# How to delete one row from database using SilverLights Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL table and I want to use SilverLight Linq-to-SQL to delete a row.
I am new to Linq-to-SQL, but the SQL statement should be

```
DELETE FROM Lloyds_Selection_Vessel WHERE Selection_ID == inpSelectionID AND ImoNumber == inpImoNumber
```

What is the Linq-to-SQL statement? 
This is my code:

```
[OperationContract]
void DeleteSelectionVesselRow(int inpSelectionID, int inpImoNumber)
{
    PositionDataClassesDataContext context = new PositionDataClassesDataContext();

    context.Lloyds_Selection_Vessels.DeleteAllOnSubmit(context.Lloyds_Selection_Vessels.Where(l => l.Selection_ID == inpSelectionID && x => x.ImoNumber == inpImoNumber));
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your LINQ Where function read:
    .Where(l => l.Selection_ID == inpSelectionID && l.ImoNumber == inpImoNumber)
instead?